# makefile pattern rules: single wildcard, multiple instances in prerequisite

Tags: makefile, design-patterns, wildcard

hopefully this is a basic question about make pattern rules:
I want to use a wildcard more than once in a prerequisite for a rule, i.e. in my Makefile I have

```
data/%P1.m: $(PROJHOME)/data/%/ISCAN/%P1.RAW
        @echo "  Writing temporary matlab file for $*"
        # do something

data/%P2.m: $(PROJHOME)/data/%/ISCAN/AGP2.RAW
            @echo "  Writing temporary matlab file for $*"
            # do something
```

In this example, I try to invoke make when the wildcard % is AG.  Both files $(PROJHOME)/data/AG/ISCAN/AGP1.RAW and $(PROJHOME)/data/AG/ISCAN/AGP2.RAW exist.  I attempt the following make commands and get this output:

```
[jshen@iLab10 gender-diffs]$ make data/AGP1.m
make: *** No rule to make target `data/AGP1.m'.  Stop.

[jshen@iLab10 gender-diffs]$ make data/AGP2.m
Writing temporary matlab file for AG, part 2...

[jshen@iLab10 gender-diffs]$ ls data/AG/ISCAN/AG*
data/AG/ISCAN/AGP1.RAW  data/AG/ISCAN/AGP2.RAW
```

How can I implement multiple instances of the same wildcard in the first make rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this seemed to work:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:    
data/%P1.m: $(PROJHOME)/data/$$*/ISCAN/$$*P1.RAW
            @echo "Writing temporary matlab file for $*, part 1..."
```